# High resolution is RGB image is not coming clear and sharp?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, image

I am woking with LISS IV image of Indian Satellite Resousesat-2. This image has 3 bands i.e., NIR, Red, and Green band and spatial resolution of five meter.

When I view the image in ArcGIS the details are not sharp as it should be. For example, below is the screenshot of the image I am using i.e., five meter spatial resolution, and a screenshot from a published article which uses similar image at Eight meter spatial resolution.

**5 m spatial resolution**
[image]

**8 m spatial resolution (screenshot from a publish article)**
[image]

Why does my image not have the fine details despite having the finer resolution than later? Why the colors are blurry for different land cover?

How to present it like the published image shown here?

Comment: There could be many reasons.  How was your image brought into ArcGIS? Have you checked the symbology settings in your layer? The bottom image looks like it has a higher contrast setting. Have you adjusted contrast? What interpolation method is Arc using to display the image? Also, it doesn't look like you're comparing the same locations, so it's hard to tell exactly if there really is a difference. Finally, they're from different sensors.  The bottom figure is from Formosat-2.

Comment: I didn't do anything with contrast. I mosaiced and layerstacked the bands in ERDAS Imagine and hen brought into ArcGIS.

Comment: Images will never be the same depending on conditions. There could be atmospheric haze, thin layer of cloud cover, etc.

Comment: Definitely, Image enhancement has been applied to the published article's image.